# Sanitize image content and remove embedded Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, security, xss

For an image upload API that we’re building, is there any guidance on checking/sanitising for malicious content ?

I’ve seen examples in the internet where we can add JavaScript inside an image and upload it to any file upload API. If we were to render the image as-is using  element elsewhere, that embedded JS code is executed by the browser.

While searching for mitigation advice, I came across this [link](https://owasp.deteact.com/cheat/cheatsheets/Protect_FileUpload_Against_Malicious_File.html) in OWASP docs. Their recommendation is to rewrite images using Apache Commons Imaging library but I’m not sure if it’s actively maintained (last update in 2020)

Is there a better way of detecting embedded JS in images (or) some safe way of rendering these images in browser to mitigate against Stored XSS attacks ?

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways to mitigate xss on image file uploads.

Follow these steps,

- Don't allow any other file types apart from images. *(For example: only accept files with content-type: `image/png`, `image/jpg`, `image/jpeg`, `image/gif`)*
- Always, save the file using an appropriate extension, never allow the user to control the extension of the filename. *(You can save the file using a completely randomname to mitigate this, use GUID/UUID to generate a random name for the image)*
- Set the HTTP Response's content type to `image/<type>`. *(Browsers won't execute any javascript if the content type is `image/*`)*
- Only use `<img src="[path-to-img]">` tag to render the image and don't allow the user to control any values of HTML here.
- If you are allowing users to upload `svg` images, then you should sanitize the content of the file because SVG files are built with XML. So, use something like [sanitize-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mattkrick/sanitize-svg) to remove malicious content from the uploaded data.
- Use CSP to prevent XSS *(Optional, better if you can implement)*

If you follow above steps, there is pretty much zero chance to get XSS. *(Currently - 2022-04-09)*
So, if you want to only protect against XSS attacks, there is no need to sanitize or detect malicious content of the uploaded data.

**[WARNING]: If you process uploaded data server-side for anything else *(resizing,cropping)*, you have to remove any malicious content before doing that.**

Finally, make sure to check this [XSS Mitigation Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) by OWASP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The image handling process you found in the OWASP docs is generally a good approach.

If you are really concerned about some malicious content than:

1. Handle the image rewrite in a disposable environment (VM or container)
   where it is not a problem if it gets compromised.
2. Keep/store the uploaded file in 2-3 fregments on the host and only assemble it in the vm.

Edit:

Plus you can use [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to protect - on the client side - the users against XSS attacks.